# Waiting image during processing

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I would like to have an animation (a GIF image) when the user clic on a button, and during the processing time.

My code :

```
 <div class="fieldV" >
                        <p:ajaxStatus onstart="statusDialog.show();" oncomplete="statusDialog.hide();"/> 

                        <p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="statusDialog"   
                                draggable="false" closable="false"> 
                            <p:graphicImage value="/images/LOADER.gif" /> 
                        </p:dialog>


                        <p:commandButton id="bvalider"  action="#{profilBean.checkProfil}" value="#{messages['content.valider']}" styleClass="buttonV"
                          update="profil" >

                        </p:commandButton> 

                    </div>
```

The problem is that nothing appears (except a modal window). The path to the image is correct (if I try to draw the image elsewhere it works), and if I replace the image by a text I have the same problem.

Comment: What happens if you try to display the image outside of the dialog? What happens if you try to display something else inside the dialog? Have you tried looking at your debugger console? JavaScript will stop processing once it hits an error, so if there is a programming problem, it may manifest by not completely drawing the modal.

Comment: Hi, thx for your answer. If I display the image outside it works. A text displayed does not work. I haven't seen any errors in the console :-(

Comment: Which version of PrimeFaces are you using? Which browser?

Comment: Also, are you actually _opening_ the modal anywhere?

Comment: Version 3.5 of primefaces with chrome and firefox. I am not sure to understand what you mean by "actulally opening the modal anywhere" but this is the only place in my implementation where I use the modal.

Comment: You need to actually show the modal. It doesn't show by default. You can do this in Java by grabbing the component and calling setVisible(true), or in JavaScript by calling widgetVar.show().

Comment: Thx for your answer. The modal window seems to be ok (I do the "show" in the ajax code) but this is the image which does not appear.

Comment: I see nothing else wrong with your code. I have almost the exact same code in my project, and it works fine for me. The only last thing I can recommend is to try toggling the `appendToBody` attribute of the dialog, to make sure that it's in a form, and to remove the dialog from the `<div>` container. Otherwise the problem is probably external to the code you've posted.

Comment: You were right, the problem was external. The webpage was too long, and the image was not appear after scrolling. I fixed it in the CSS and now it is ok. Thx for all your advices.